# Prohibit capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is there a tricky way to prevent an object from being captured by reference into a lamba?  For example, I'd like to disallow this:

```
class A {};

void Foo()
{
    A a;
    auto lamda = [&a](){};      // Disallow this
    // give lambda to async process
    // use A to help know when the lamda finally gets called
}
```

I want to prevent this because `A` could be easily misused in this context, so I'd like to prevent the user from harming themselves.  One could argue that any class can be misused, but given `A`'s contract it is *really* tempting for a user to do this.  I have the freedom to wrap, change, and otherwise obfuscate A as much as needed.

---

**Edit**

After the lambda is created it is handed off to an asynchronous process while the current thread waits inline until that asynchronous process has completed.  `A` is a class to help know when the async operation completes (think `boost::future`).

Comment: Would making all the methods of ``A`` ``const`` prevent the misuse?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the issue is A leaving scope while the lambda is still finishing up its last tidbit of work.  Unless there was a way to make it const when capturing by reference?

Comment: Just make sure you crash loudly when it is misused.

Comment: I'm just grasping at straws, but could you declare a operator& for A and make it private?

Comment: @HansPassant Have a clever way to even detect this situation?  I would settle for that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `operator&` is not called here.

Comment: I'm not sure how ``a`` could leave the scope before the lambda is done with it. Unless you are launching something asynchronously.

Comment: I did think it might be too easy (and I did say I was guessing!)

Comment: @JaredC How does that happen exactly? Does the lambda do asynchronous work? Is it exported outside its scope?

Comment: Perhaps you can make `A` a private nested type in some other class which could control access to those objects carefully?

Comment: @AndreiTita Yes, there is asynchronous work and waiting involved, which are omitted to make the example simple.

Comment: @KerrekSB `A` is a small enough class that I may be able to wrap the member functions by ones that copy A and then operate on the copy.  Making a safe copy will be tricky, but given the interface I can be sure the user won't accidentally destroy A before even calling any functions on it.  Hmm....

Comment: @AndreiTita: It does not have to do anything asynchronous. e.g. if the lambda is stored in a global variable or instance variable of an object somewhere that that lives longer than this function; or the lambda is returned, then that will happen.

Comment: @newacct Yes, that was covered by the "exported outside its scope" part. It's easier to educate people that exporting a reference-capturing lambda is akin to returning a reference to temporary (DON'T!) than it is to make them figure out when asynchronous work will finish.

Comment: @AndreiTita Education is good, but compiler errors are better :-)

Comment: *What is your situation where this is your solution?* Why not tell us more about `A` so we can help you solve the apparently poor design of A?

Comment: @GManNickG: This happens with expression template type things, where you want a function to be called at the end of the full expression, and you do that by returning a type that converts to the real return type, but who's destructor calls your function.  This goes awry if the user stores that temporary.

Comment: @GManNickG: I did this recently for a "function" that would release ownership of a `unique_ptr`, pass a pointer to the value to a function (COM), and then after that function completed, restore ownership to the `unique_ptr`: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=09acbd607d45bb941fcde44f572f50b9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. Any lvalue of type `T` can bind to a variable of type `T &`. You can't prevent an object from being the value of an lvalue expression (e.g. an id-expression).

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is just syntactic sugar for a function object. The lambda above is essentially equivalent to something like this:

```
class SomeAnonymousFunctor {
    A &a;
public:
    SomeAnonymousFunctor(A &foo) : a(foo) {}
    void operator()() const {}
};

void Foo()
{
    A a;
    auto lamda = SomeAnonymousFunctor(a);      // Disallow this
}
```

So you see, to deal with the underlying problem, now you have to either disallow a constructor or function accepting type `A &`, or disallow storing type `A &` inside a class.

Comment: And how are you going to do this?